# Double summation with dependent indices

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I would like to show that

$ \sum_{N=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^N f\left(n, N-n\right)$

is equal to

$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{N-n=0}^\infty f\left(n, N-n\right).$

I can convince myself that this holds by expanding both sums to some finite (small) order and checking that every $f(x, y)$ is counted precisely once, with $x$ and $y$ varying independently.

Is there a more general or concise way of proving the equivalence of these two sums than just expanding it out and somehow "seeing" that they count every $f$ once and only once?

Comment: For any $n$ the inequality $N-n \geq 0$ is same as $n \leq N$. That is all you need to say that the sums are equal.

Comment: My usual explanation is also to have expanded it out a bit and describe the first sum as having added over the grid from left-to-right followed by top-to-down while the second sum as having added over the grid from top-to-down followed by from left-to-right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

False.

Let $f(n,k)=1$ if $k\neq0$ and $f(n,0)=-n$.

The first sum converges, since the inner sum is always $0$.

The second does not converge, as the inner sum always diverges.